# Full Screen mode in iOS7 Safari

Tags: ios, ios7, sencha-touch, mobile-safari

I am developing a mobile web site using Sencha Touch. In iOS7 Safari I cannot make the top address bar & the toolbar below go away. Sencha used to handle this upto iOS6 but some recent changes in iOS7 is causing this issue.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/safari-ios-7-and-html5
I read the above link & it seems this is also an issue for HTML5 Games & a few other apps.
The old window.scrollTo() which worked for iOS6 no longer works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `minimal-ui` in your meta tag `viewport`, this will hide he address bar and browser controls in safari iOS7:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

More info on iOS7 and fullscreen mode for mobile websites: http://blog.initlabs.com/post/81716286465/how-to-display-websites-in-fullscreen-mode-in-ios7

Comment: The golden ticket was the minimal-ui parameter.

Answer (score 5):

With iOS 7 I don't think you really have a choice. Obviously Apple doesn't want developers doing this anymore, and even if someone finds another workaround it probably won't stick around for that long.

Honestly, I think getting fullscreen functionality is a fair trade off for users to install the app to their home screen. Obviously there are certain cases where this isn't true, but I guess I find it understandable to some degree. You should still be able to add the following meta tag and it will be fullscreen once added to home screen:
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

There are a few nice libraries out there that add an "add to homescreen" prompt that you can set up to be rather unobtrusive with custom messages. In this case, might be best to embrace the change...